# Точка в конце прямречи

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно?

> 1.1. Мой папа сказал: «Мама сказала: „Я не дома – на даче!“»

> 1.2. Мой папа сказал: «Мама сказала: „Я не дома – на даче!“».

> 2.1. Мой папа сказал: «Мама сказала: „Я не дома – на даче“.»

> 2.2. Мой папа сказал: «Мама сказала: „Я не дома – на даче“.».

> 2.3. Мой папа сказал: «Мама сказала: „Я не дома – на даче“».

Comment: А варианта с восклицательным знаком, но без точки нет?

Comment: Что-то зарябило в глазах :)) В упор не вижу разницы между 1.1. и 1.2.

Comment: Исправил. Простите.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

*Мой папа сказал: "**Мама сказала**, я не дома – на даче".*

*Мой папа сказал: "**Мама сказала,** я не дома – на даче!"*

Здесь **вводное предложение** вместо слов автора.

Comment: I made those sentences on purpose! I don't accept rewording my sentences, which Mr. Буратино loves to do!

Comment: Really, sir, I didn't mean to offend you, but is such syntax possible? If you specify the source, I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: I am asking about the period, whether to put it or not.

Comment: Sir, but if such a construction does not exist, then what is the point in solving such a problem? However, it will also be interesting for me to look at such a solution.

Comment: I had to write those sentences, which all have two direct speech clauses, and I didn't know whether the period had to be put or not.